# Angular CORS: PUT missing Authorization header after OPTIONS preflight

Tags: angular, nginx, cors, logstash

I want to send data from Angular into Logstash HTTP input. Because Logstash HTTP input doesn't handle the CORS preflight request gracefully ([can't disable basic authentication for OPTIONS](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-http/issues/83)), I want to use nginx in front of Logstash as a proxy. The relevant part of my nginx configuration is as follows:

```
location / {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' true;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type,accept,origin,X-Requested-With';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type,accept,origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Disposition';

    return 200;

    limit_except OPTIONS {
        auth_basic "Restricted access zone";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:31311;  # logstash listens here
    }
}
```

This works fine for allowing the OPTIONS. Relevant cURL output (from Chrome's "Copy as cURL" function:

```
> OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
> Host: MUNGED
> Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
> Origin: MUNGED
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Accept-Language: en-IL,en;q=0.9,he-IL;q=0.8,he;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/71.0.3578.80 Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36
> Accept: */*
> Referer: MUNGED
> Connection: keep-alive
> DNT: 1
> Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
> 
{ [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Tue, 25 Dec 2018 20:13:01 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type,accept,origin,X-Requested-With
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type,accept,origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Disposition
```

(I'm not sure if `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` is necessary, but it doesn't work either way...)

However, for some reason, the subsequent PUT fails because the Authorization header isn't sent in the request. The relevant Angular code looks something like:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders();                                                                                                                                                  
headers.set('Authorization', 'basic ' + btoa(environment.eventUsername + ':' + environment.eventPassword));                                                                         
headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');                                                                                                                                    
this.httpClient.put(environment.eventTrackingUrl, event, { headers: headers }).subscribe();
```

However, the PUT headers look like this (again using copy to cURL):

```
> PUT / HTTP/1.1
> Host: MUNGED
> Origin: MUNGED
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Accept-Language: en-IL,en;q=0.9,he-IL;q=0.8,he;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/71.0.3578.80 Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
> Referer: MUNGED
> Connection: keep-alive
> DNT: 1
> Content-Length: 144
> 
} [144 bytes data]
* upload completely sent off: 144 out of 144 bytes
{ [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Tue, 25 Dec 2018 21:03:34 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 606
< Connection: keep-alive
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted access zone"
```

No Authorization header... This results in the PUT failing with a 401.

Any clues as to why Angular or the browser isn't sending the Authorization header?

Comment: In your frontend Angular request code, are you setting 'withCredentials: true'?

Comment: No, according to the documentation it's deprecated, but the replacement docs don't explain anything about credentials! I actually opened an issue about it tonight... Any insights into this matter? Very confusing. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27828

Comment: You could send the request directly with the native fetch API instead, with `credentials: 'include'`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Sending_a_request_with_credentials_included

Comment: I'm not sure that will work in my use case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials. I need the wildcard because we need to accept requests from whitelabelled domains.

Comment: If you have a discrete set of known whitelabelled domains, the then way to deal with that is it maintain the set in your server application code and have your server application-code logic check the value of the Origin request header against that set,  and if there’s a match, then take the value of the Origin request header and use it to set the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header.

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";` for now in nginx, and it seems to work. Currently testing `fetch()`.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Well, first somebody pointed out that `withCredentials` isn't deprecated (see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27828), but it still didn't work for me, it opened a basic auth dialog... But `fetch()` did work, so thanks a lot! Do you want to add it as an answer, so I can accept it?